# What is the probability of two people having two identical scars?

Tags: time-travel, law, identity

What is the probability of two people having the same scar on their body in the same spot and the same shape and the same backstory (drunk driver in a chevy '78) Could the scar be a viable form of identification?

Would it trump a witness in a police report? Would a security camera in Wisconsin showing an individual having this scar be believed more than a witness that recognized the individual's face in a crime scene in Florida?
What if both are eye witnesses?

The main topics here are police identification and social recognition. (That is the same scar, seize him! vs That is the same scar, what a freak coincidence!)

The scar complexity also have a role, a simple stab wound on the upper arm would be dismissed as coincidence, but the scar I'm talking about is a combined scar from an accident and a surgery in the shape of the state of Idaho. The scars sizes and details play a big role in identification/recognition.

The individual is a time-traveler and may or may not have been involved in a crime with witnesses identifying his face.

**Major Edit**

The world I'm designing contains a number of **Iterative Persons (IP)**, that means if a person dies he will be reincarnated into an other person born on the same exact moment. The memories are little tricky, the **IP** will remember the events of previous days for all other instances depending on the number of times they fell asleep. i.e: the instance 4 when he wakes up for the 3650th time in their life will remember the memories all previous instances (1,2,3) have when they fall asleep for the 3650th time, regardless of their time or age. The **IP** is able to sense that these memories are from other instances and can (more or less) know to which instance they belong to. This also affects scars so everyone will have the same scars (not injuries) appear on them upon waking up.

One day, instance 14 wakes up with 3 years worth of memories and a gun shot <s>wound</s> scar on his forehead and a large exit <s>wound</s> scar on the back of his head.

Would having the same scars will cause people to suspect two iterations are the same person or an **IP**? Can this be used to 'Help' previous instances by providing alibi in crimes?

Comment: @L.Dutch I agree to the addition of the `justice` and `identity` tags. But i failed to mention in the question that the person involved could be a time traveler hence the `time-travel` tag you removed. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: _Is_ it possible? Yes. The outcome of two independent chaotic systems being the same is possible, but unlikely enough that it would be considered an outlier by any decent model.  Your several hundred thousand trillion to one chance. Calculating the probability for such a thing is meaningless. Identifying marks were used in the past, but were abandoned after good quality photographs came out because people are horrible at describing complex shapes. If it comes to an alibi versus eyewitness ID based solely on the scar, the defendant will walk. In summary, good for a plot twist, but not realistic

Comment: This isn't a worldbuilding question; there's nothing about your world you are trying to develop. This question is about hammering out the details of your plot, figuring out if a given plot point is viable.

Comment: If the scar is put their deliberately as a move to steal identity, 100%.

Comment: Can a scar be used for identification: no. Can a scar confuse police investigation or criminal trial: yes.

Comment: Too easy to do intentionally.

Comment: I just so happen to have a scar that is a perfect map of the London underground, so that makes the odds pretty good.

Comment: @wedstrom Falling asleep on the map doesn't count :P.... How did you get it?

Comment: @workoverflow Same way as Dumbledore. Hopefully we'll find out in the next Fantastic Beasts movie.

Comment: @wedstrom -_- I should be ashamed of myself for not getting that reference.

Comment: @workoverflow Haha it was subtle :P

Answer (score 15):

Last time I checked my ID card it reported data about my hair color, my eye color, my height and a picture of my face. No mentions to scars, even though I have some scattered all over my body.

Same at airports, I got my face scanned for matching with my passport, not my scars.

Scars are not good as primary identifiers, simply because it's too easy to counterfeit them and they are also not stable over time. And most of them are so common that they are practically worthless. Just think of appendix surgery: how many people have that scar in their lower abdomen? Or how many skiers have scars on their knee, as consequence of snapped tendons in ski related accidents?

Scarface, just to give you an example, was well known for this feature, but nobody started arresting people with a scar on their faces just because "hey, they have a scar on their face!".

*Addendum after OP's comment*: about large scars, our brain is developed to quickly identify faces, not scars. Telling the difference between two look alike scars would take much more training and inspection than telling the difference between two look alike faces. Still I see no reason for basing the identification on solely one plausible scar (with plausible I mean that I don't imagine a scar coming i.e. with an unique serial number).

Comment: My thoughts exactly, but would a complex scar be sufficient as an alibi? like tattoos but less replicable as in the case of an accident? (think large burn victims with distinct scarring on face/hands)

Comment: @workoverflow, alibi? you probably mean something else

Comment: I think he means allibi as in somebody saw the scar at a day and time the character is suspected to have done something elsewhere

Comment: My first passport had a section called "Identifiable Features", back when they were handwritten. Things like a visible mole or scar would be entered there

Comment: @nzaman, but those would support your identification. Not be the main identifier.

Comment: Commenting on your first paragraph. Visible marks as identifiers did use to be a thing

Comment: As an addendum to the addendum, people tend to notice and remember the part that sticks out. A witness that saw a man with a large complex facial scar would remember a large complex facial scar, not the exact appearance of the scar and possibly not even the appearance of the man.

Comment: @workoverflow Scars might be able to create an "alibi" of sorts because of their absence, e.g. "The perpetrator's face was not caught on film, but you can clearly see that his back has no scars unlike the accused", but going the other direction where a person has a scar that looks a lot like one on film or in testimony would need to be REALLY unique and REALLY clearly identical to be comparable to a face in terms of identification.

Comment: This doesn't address the question of how likely would it be for two scars to be identical.

Comment: Concerning the alibi, a clever, sufficiently skilled criminal could conceal his scars and create fake ones on a different person using makeup. (How fitting, on Halloween) This will of course not hold up to close scrutiny once he is in police custody, but it can definitely fool witnesses and cameras in the moment of the crime, which would be enough.

Comment: Although this does not directly answer the probability question, this challenges the premise, and has given sufficient reasoning why it is not viable.

Answer (score 8):

If the scar is caused by some kind of machine, and the accident involving the machine is typical for its use, then having the same injury is not outrageous.  They would have the same story concerning the injury, too.

For surgery, the doctor would normally use a standard incision based on the specific operation, right?

You can probably contrive reasons why it is less of a coincidence, and work that into the plot.

Comment: Don't forget gang affiliation as well

Comment: @Separatrix Or pockmarked face from massive acne problems.

Answer (score 7):

In an accident the odds of getting the same scars would be sod all, even twins being used as crash-test dummies would struggle to get identical wounds from the same impact test, at the same speed, in the same model of vehicle. A crash is a chaotic system, in the mathematical sense that there are too many variables to account for, where you can't predict exact outcomes based on the measurable variables at the time of the incident. As to the surgical scars, two surgeons dealing with wounds that were extremely similar might cause a near match in final, treated formation, if they were in the same year, with the same teachers during their time as students and so learned the same techniques. Even if it was the same wound treated by the same surgeon it probably wouldn't heal the same way for two different people though.

As to the rest anything I say about the legal/prosecution side of the question would be bare speculation and pretty pointless, it's purely the realm of the story teller to speak to those issues.

Comment: What does "sod all" mean here?  "Extremely unlikely"?  "Nigh impossible"?  I'm from America (I'm assuming you're British, because I've never heard the phrase "sod all" before, but it sounds quite British).

Comment: @BenSandeen I'm in New Zealand but yes the expression is a British one and it yes means there is very little chance at all of such an occurrence, I believe there is an Americanism "the chances are between nil and zip"? That would equally apply here.